# Are there any conjectures known not to be independent that have neither been proven true or false?

Tags: provability

Are there any known conjectures that have been shown not to be independent of whatever system they target (i.e. provable), but have not yet been shown to be true or false?

Comment: @lordoftheshadows Surely we haven't shown that all open problems are provable within whichever axioms they target?

Comment: @lordoftheshadows Well, many conjectures I know have not been shown not to be independant.

Comment: Is the $10^{1000}$'th decimal place of $\pi$ even or odd?

Comment: Sure! "Conjecture, there is a Mersenne prime between the two current largest Mersenne primes." 

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_prime

Could be false, could be true, can be computed and checked in finite time.